# Tesseract False Space Recognition

Tags: c++, opencv, ocr, tesseract, spaces

I'm using tesseract to recognize a serial number. This works acceptable, common problem like false recognition of zero and "O", 6 and 5, or M and H exists. 
Beside by this tesseract adds spaces to the recognized words, where no space is in the image. The following image is recognized as **"HI 3H"**.

[image: Example Image 1]

This image results in **" FBKHJ 1R1"**

[image: Example image 2]

So tesseract added a space, although there isn't really a space in the image. 
Is there a possibility parametrize the spacing behavior of tesseract?

**Edit**

I'm sorry, have forgot to add, that I also have serial numbers which include spaces. So I cannot delete all spaces inside the recognized serial number.

For example the following image containing a space in the serial number results after tesseract recognition into: **J4 F1583BB**. Beside that the recognition of the characters is false, the space is recognized correct with this image.

[image: Example image 3]

My actual parameters for tesseract are:

```
tesseract::TessBaseAPI tess;
tess.Init(NULL, "eng", tesseract::OEM_TESSERACT_ONLY);
tess.SetPageSegMode(tesseract::PSM_SINGLE_BLOCK);
tess.SetVariable("tessedit_char_whitelist",
            "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ012345789");

char* out = tess.GetUTF8Text();
string text = string(out);
```

**Edit**

It is notices from already existing answers, that the space between the "J" and "I" for example seems to be little more, than between the other characters. The font-type I have chosen is a Monotype Font. Reason for this is that I thought, that this helps tesseract for character recognition. Drawback of such a Monospace font-type, where every character has the same  width, is that the kernel (the space between the characters) varies. 
See example image of following source [Source](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Typeface)

[image: Proportional vs. Monospace]

Which font type do you think, will achieve better recognition results?

Comment: As a lazy dude, I would ask if your serials will ever contain a space?

Comment: sorry, edited my question, serial numbers including spaces exists...

Comment: When you call `Init` on your `TessBaseAPI` object, you pass in "eng" as the second parameter. Is that to specify the character set or the language? If the latter, can you change it to an option that refers to just alphanumeric characters, but doesn't have the semantics of English proper?

Comment: dont know about you, but the distance between J and I in `FBK` may be a space, even for a human

Comment: @RedRoboHood: The init Function requires a language parameter, as far as i know. In general the serialnumber is language independent.

Comment: @UmNyobe: Yeah, I see that there is a little a distance between this characters, Since I have created the serialnumbers, and took the photos I know that there shouldn't be a space. I thought tesseract does something like, checking the mean distance between the characters and therefore can distinguish between spaces and belonging characters. 
If there is no option or parameter so set in tesseract, I would write a function to calculate the mean distance between characters out of the bounding boxes and checks if two boxes are too far and therefore result in a spacing in between.

Comment: Should I recreate the serial numbers trying to use the same space between all characters. In general it is to say, that if to less space is between the characters tesseract can not distinguish between individual characters.

Comment: same problem in 2009: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/tesseract-ocr/5_3N6NShQck I guess there isn't such a parameter, but not guarantee... BUT maybe... have a look at `textord/tospace.cpp` as suggested by https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/tesseract-ocr/PepNaRySaHw/XzmKb_yZ7mkJ (all found on google)

Comment: OK, Thank you. I have searched already too before opening a new question :) 
But haven't found something useful, ... But I will have a deeper look at the cpp file you mentioned.

Comment: What happened to the number "6"?  Your variable `tessedit_char_whitelist` has excluded that digit!?

Answer (score 6):

Adjusting parameter `tosp_min_sane_kn_sp` may help. I solved the problem by doing it.

If it doesn't help, you may try other  `tosp_*` paramters, or working around the space source code "tospace.cpp"

Answer (score 0):

I'm not C++ programmer but i think that it's possible to calibrate the width of each letter space. I found this parameter *"textord_space_size_is_variable*" in this [site](http://www.sk-spell.sk.cx/tesseract-ocr-parameters-in-302-version), and it says *"If true, word delimiter spaces are assumed to have variable width, even though characters have fixed pitch."*

Good luck! :)

Comment: Haven't seen that there are that much parameter adjustable. I will give them a try, Thank you.